# Field in Infopath form missing from Sharepoint List form

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, infopath

I have an Infopath form which when clicking submit, posts the data to the associated fields in a Sharepoint document library. The issue I have is this;

**1.** Field is 'Request Date'.

**2.** When editing the Sharepoint list item that is created when submitting the Infopath form, this column/field is not visible (have checked to make sure it is a promoted field in Infopath when publishing).

**3.** When I go to my Sharepoint List settings - I can see the column is there however I cannot click it to configure etc.

**4.** Have checked Advanced settings and 'Allow Management of content types' is set to 'Yes'

**5.** Checked the form content type settings (to see if the column is set to 'hidden' however presented with same issue in point 3 above.

**6.** If, however, I create a new 'view' and include the column, it will show and is capturing the data entered into the InfoPath form.

I hope I'm making sense - I am some-what new to InfoPath and Sharepoint but don't recall ever seeing this happen in the past. Any guidance here would be extremely appreciated as I can't think of anything else to rectify at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of this column?

When you create a new item in the list, can you see this column in the new form?

You could try to delete it then re-add,compare the result.

Comment: Hi Emily, Thanks for the response. It's a Date formatted column in a Document Library (not a standard list). When a new item is created in the list (this happens when an Infopath form is submitted) - the List entry does not show the column. As per above, it seems to only be visible when creating a view and selecting the column.

I am wondering if I can can not promote the field when publishing the Infopath form, then re-promote it and publish? Just worried I will loose historical data already held on the Sharepoint list?

Comment: It's so wired. When you delete the column, the data stored in the column will be deleted. I suggest you re-create a column then re-publish the form.